# Which are best for Name Entity Recognition for Gujarati Language Text?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am finding out the best working models for Name Entity Recognition in Gujarati Text. I know only 1 of them that is Indic Bert model of hugging face. Can anyone suggest other model which documentation or code available for Name Entity Recognition in Gujarati Language??

I found only IndicBERT model of Hugging Face. I want know other mode or any link where the code is available for Name Entity Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

The recent work Joshi [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.11418.pdf) offers L3Cube-GujaratiBERT, available on HuggingFace [here](https://huggingface.co/l3cube-pune/gujarati-bert/blob/main/README.md). You'll have to fine-tune the model on your specific down-stream task (i.e. Named Entity Recognition in Gujarati). There is a list of Indic NER datasets [here](https://github.com/AI4Bharat/indicnlp_catalog#ner-corpora), of relevance to your problem is the [AI4Bharat Naamapadam](https://huggingface.co/datasets/ai4bharat/naamapadam) dataset which has Gujarati as one of the 11 available Indic languages.

##### Additional Info

In [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.11418.pdf), Joshi initially created the L3Cube-HindBERT and L3Cube-DevBERT models pre-trained on Hindi and Devanagari script (Hindi + Marathi) monolingual corpora, respectively. These offered a modest improvement in performance over the alternative MuRIL, IndicBERT and XLM-R multi-lingual offerings. Given the improvement, the author released other Indic language-based models, namely: Kannada, Telugu, Malayalam, Tamil, **Gujarati**, Assamese, Odia, Bengali, and Punjabi (all can be found at https://huggingface.co/l3cube-pune).

### References

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.11418.pdf) Joshi, R., 2022. L3Cube-HindBERT and DevBERT: Pre-Trained BERT Transformer models for Devanagari based Hindi and Marathi Languages. arXiv preprint arXiv:2211.11418.